# spark hive java.lang.linkageerror

Tags: apache-spark, spark-hive

When executing Drop table if exists in Spark HiveContext I'm getting the below error.

> Hivecontext.sql(Drop table if exists table_name)
>
> java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to
> castjar:file:/u/applic/data/hdfs7/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/494/spark-hdp-assembly.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.classtojar:file:/u/applic/data/hdfs7/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/494/spark-hdp-assembly.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class

I'm using:

- Spark Version - Spark 1.6,
- HDP -  2.4

Comment: Hi Arun, any updates on the same or any resolution...getting the same exception